# representation of association in c++

Tags: c++

I want to represent UML type of association using C++. Unfortunetely I get error at

```
AssociationsP = new Player[n];
```

which is: "no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'. What am I missing? Is this concept even okay?

```
class Player;
class Team;

class Player {
private:
    int n;
    Team * AssociationsT;
public:
    Player(int x) : n(x) {
        AssociationsT = new Team[n];
    }
    void setTeam(Team * t) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            AssociationsT[i] = t[i];
        }
    }
};

class Team {
private:
    int n;
    Player * AssociationsP;
public:
    Team(int x) : n(x) {
        AssociationsP = new Player[n];
    }
    void setPlayer(Player * p) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            AssociationsP[i] = p[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, how do you imagine your `n` player objects would be initialized?

Comment: I imagine it that somewhere in the main function I will have definitions:
Team t1(2);
Player p1(1);
Player p2(1);
And then setFunction invokes.

Comment: @monterinio: What do you think happens when calling `AssociationsP = new Player[n];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might want something along the lines of the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Team;

class Player {
    const std::string name_;
    std::vector<const Team*> AssociationsT;
public:
    Player(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { }
    void setTeam(const Team& t) {
        AssociationsT.push_back(&t);
    }
};

class Team {
    const std::string name_;
    std::vector<const Player*> AssociationsP;
public:
    Team(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { }
    void setPlayer(const Player& p) {
        AssociationsP.push_back(&p);
    }
};

void assignPlayerToTeam(Player& player, Team& team)
{
    team.setPlayer(player);
    player.setTeam(team);
}

int main()
{
    Player bill("Bill");
    Team cubs("Cubs");

    assignPlayerToTeam(bill, cubs);
}
```

Comment: Does it make a huge difference if I use a list instead of vector?

Comment: @monterinio: You don't get indexing (so you can't say `AssociationsP[3]`), you can't pass it to C code and a `list` is usually less efficient, apart from that not really.